# sending email from wave robot

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, google-wave

Anyone know how to send an email using google wave python api?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a wave robot is nothing special here - you've got to determine at what point you want to send email, but you haven't told us anything about that, so it's hard to advise you.

When you've worked out what you want to send, just follow the normal instructions for [sending email from Python in AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html).

Comment: Now you're invading the google-app-engine tag? Curse you, Jon Skeet! ;)